Parse ByteArray (csv) and copy fields into String-Array (KOTLIN)
From a BT communication I receive a CSV byteArray like: PF;01;ABC;123456;EXAMPLE;
The number of field and the content is variable.
I would like to parse the byteArray and push the fields in an ARRAY of STRINGS for later interpretation.
I am using the following code, but it is not working, since I do not get the STRING Array properly initialised. Any support is appreciated ... and excuse my basic way of programming ;-) all goes back to AMIGA BASIC and ASSEMBLER (35 years ago).
private fun processMessage(value: ByteArray) {
    val fields = Array<String>(100,"".toString())
    
    var j = 0
    var k = 0
    for (i in value.indices) {
        if (value[i]==";".toByte()) {
            fields[k] = value.copyOfRange(j,i-1).toString()
            j=i+1
            k++
        }
    }
}


private fun processMessage(value: ByteArray): List<String> {

    val line = "${value.toString(Charsets.UTF_8)}"
    val values = line.split(";")
    return values 
}


The array initialization is done in a function block (i.e. lambda):
val fields = Array(100) { "" }

You also have an issue with your delimiter (the ;) not being correctly converted, and the output is also not properly handled.
I would use another approach entirely, something like this:
private fun processMessage(value: ByteArray): List<String> {
    val delimiter = ';'.code.toByte()
    val fields = mutableListOf<String>()
    val currentField = StringBuilder()

    value.forEach {
        if (it == delimiter) {
            if (currentField.isNotEmpty()) fields.add(currentField.toString())
            currentField.clear()
        } else {
            currentField.append(it.toInt().toChar())
        }
    }

    return fields
}

As a final note, please keep in mind that CSV is not standardized and that there are variations on how delimiters and line breaks occurring as part of a value are escaped. The above code cannot handle any escape sequences. If that is something that you need you need to adapt the code according to the escape mechanism used for the input.

Thanks for that! It help me to understand how to basically handle the String-Array. Meanwhile I was playing around with an older java code and found a 2-line-solution. Which I add below for every bodies reference.

Yes of course, that is even better. My attention was caught by your loop and I entirely failed to see the big picture. Good catch!

I learn everyday something new ;-)
